# Ubuntu 16.04 install pip for python 3.4.4

Tags: python

I need to use Python 3.4.4 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. After installing Python 3.4.4 I do not have pip installed with it

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.4: No module named pip
```

How do I install pip specifically for python 3.4.4?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version? There is a similar sounding bug for e.g. 15.10 noted on launchpad ... [No way to install pip for Python 3.4 in 15.10 Wily](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1506907)

Comment: Usually "need to use" is to be distinguished mainly into either a) as system python and b) for a specific application (project) python. The former should be offered by Ubuntu ecosystem (but is v3.5.1 in my knowledge) otherwise might be brittle, the latter sounds more like using virtualenv to ensure separation of concerns and not open up to frustrating mix ups.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing python3.4

Comment: by default my lubuntu 16.04 has python 3.5.1 installed.  Is there a reason you wanted to go back to 3.4?  If so, have you considered virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper?  They both come with their own pip

Comment: Thanks. I will use the virtualenv, seems like it's the best solution.

Comment: `apt-get install python3-pip`?

Comment: This installs pip for python 3.5+